# How to change the output of a dictionary format in to another

Tags: python, dictionary

My Dictionary is below

```
    d = {
   "interface": [
      {
         "device": "device1",
         "keyvalue": [
            {
               "id": 1,
               "ipv4-address": "192.168.1.1",
               },
            {
               "id": 2,
               "ipv4-address": "192.168.1.2",
                          }
         ],
         "physical": [
            {
               "id": "1",
               "interface": "0/0"

            },
            {
               "id": "2",
               "interface": "0/1"

            }

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My desired output

`keys_ipv4_address_1 192.168.1.1
physical_interface_2 0/1`

Here  keys_ipv4_address_1 means interface['device']['keyvalue']['id' = 1]['ipv4-address']

physical_interface_2 means interface['device']['id' = 2]['interface']

My Code is below

```
for k,v in d.items():
    #print (v)
    for i in v:
        print (i['keyvalue'][0])
        print (i['physical'][1])
```

But I want the output in different format, how to achieve that. like `physical_interface_2` means go to `physical` then `interface` then id `2`

Comment: Okay. Please clarify the question ?

Comment: Please clarify what part of this task you're stuck on. Preferably, show us the code you're working on and describe exactly how it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about use recursive print to indicate which part is handling, such as

```py
def recursive_print(a, output):
    if type(a) == str:
            print(output, a)
            return
    if type(a) == int:
            print(output, a)
            return
    if type(a) == list:
            for i in a:
                recursive_print(i, output)
            return
    if type(a) == dict:
            for key in a:
                recursive_print(a[key], output + ('_' if output else '') + key)
            return
```

Then call `recursive_print(d, "")` to print the path:

```py
interface_device device1
interface_keyvalue_id 1
interface_keyvalue_ipv4-address 192.168.1.1
interface_keyvalue_id 2
interface_keyvalue_ipv4-address 192.168.1.2
interface_physical_id 1
interface_physical_interface 0/0
interface_physical_id 2
interface_physical_interface 0/1
```